# Is every convergent sequence Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis

Wikipedia: "Every convergent sequence (with limit s, say) is a Cauchy sequence, since, given any real number ε > 0, beyond some fixed point, every term of sequence is within distance ε/2 of s, so any two terms of the sequence are within distance ε of each other." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence

1. Cauchy sequence in $ L^p(\mu) : \forall \epsilon>0 \space{ } \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n,m>N \space{} ||f_n(x)-f_m(x)||_p<\epsilon $
2. Pointwise convergent sequence: $\forall \epsilon>0 \space{ } \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N \space{} |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $
3. Uniformly convergent sequence (on set $E$): $\forall \epsilon>0 \space{ } \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall x \in E, \forall n>N \space{} |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon $

However $L^p$ norm $(\int_X|f_n-f_m|^p  d{\mu})^{\frac{1}{p}}$  is not the same as the absolute value in 2. and 3. So is the Wikipedia claim true?

Comment: A general comment: You should try to make your title reflective of the question you are asking. A math question: What do you mean by absolute convergence? I am not sure what this means

Comment: the term "absolute convergence " is used for series and not sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the definition of Cauchy sequence can be given in any metric space $(X,d)$ as Wikipedia points out, while the notion of converging sequence requires only a topology on a set to be well-defined (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence)). So, if you can understand the sketch of proof given by Wikipedia and write it down rigourously, you'll see that it works for every metric space: you just have to substitute the absolute value of the difference of two real numbers, which is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, with the given distance for an arbitrary metric space. $L^{p}$ does not make any difference, since it is a metric space with the distance induced by $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert_{p}$ norm.